# How to stop Puppet applying a configuration when there is an error?

Tags: puppet

I am currently hitting, for me, somewhat unintuitive behaviour in Puppet - most likely because I don't completely understand the Puppet ethos yet.

**OK** I have a simple `puppetsimple.sh` running in the puppet agent which is applying configurations from puppet master. This is all running smoothly and as expected.

**Unintuitive (for me)** However when I, as part of setting up master, create an error, and then run `puppetsimple.sh` in the agent, it will strike the error, notify me of it, and continue to apply all the other changes for that configuration.

This effectively leaves the agent in a broken state, because it pushes ahead even when there is an error.

Is there a setting somewhere to say "hey, if you strike an error, stop, revert to how you were, and carry on your merry way"?

Given the example below. I am intentionally enabling an invalid conf file (.confX) - I get notified of the error, but it continues to populate "index.html" with "Hello World 3".

```
define a2ensite {
        exec { 'a2ensite':
                path => [ '/bin', '/usr/bin', '/usr/sbin' ],
                command => "a2ensite ${title}",
                notify => Service['apache2'],
        }
}


class mysite {

        include apache

        file { '/etc/apache2/sites-available/mysite.example.org.conf':
                owner => root,
                group => root,
                mode => 0644,
                source => "puppet:///files/mysite/mysite_apache.conf",
                notify => Service['apache2'],
        }


        a2ensite { 'mysite.example.org.confX': }


        file { ['/home/', '/home/www/', '/home/www/mysite.example.org']:
                ensure => directory,
                owner => root,
                group => root,
                mode => 0755,
        }


        file { '/home/www/mysite.example.org/index.html':
                owner => www-data,
                group => www-data,
                mode => 755,
                content => "Hello World 3",
        }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If one reosurce failing means that another resource should not be modified, then that is a dependency relationship that you need to model via `require`. A failing dependency will cause puppet to skip those resources.

But, in general, puppet does not stop or rollback runs when it hits an error. If you need to rollback, it is on you to either revert to an older puppet configuration or use some other capability to revert the node.